# How do I add custom html code to a wordpress widget so that it's css won't break theme styling?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I want to add [such intro](https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/emNLGz) (that I have found on Codepen) to my website, i.e. to the top full-width widget on the home page, but its' styles contradict with theme's CSS.

How can I make this work on my home page? Is there any plugin needed for embedding HTML code into the WordPress Text widget, or what? Thank for the answer.

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgb(23,41,58); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%, rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(23,41,58,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(52,73,94,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#17293a', endColorstr='#34495e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any access to the modify/write files? Or are you limited to CMS administration?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your carvas tags inside a new tags and edit that CSS class:

```
<div id="new-id"><carvas></carvas></div>
```

What I suggest you is download a plugin called "simple css" and change the classes and the Id inside the "simple css" interface, and edit your "new-id" CSS.

```css
new-id {
  background: rgb(23,41,58); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%, rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(23,41,58,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(52,73,94,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(23,41,58,1) 0%,rgba(52,73,94,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#17293a', endColorstr='#34495e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

also you can add a new widget type Text in your sidebar and edit the widget as you want using new CSS classes or ID.

Answer (score 0):

before copy / pasting code I thin you need to look a bit to [CSS SELECTOR](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for understand what the code you copy do in most part.

The codepen you link is composed mostly by JS and a bit of CSS.

Your CSS code focus the all the element (*) and all the content of the page (body), before implementing you need to isolate theses CSS selectors to one div who will load the canvas.

You didn't even talk about the javascript part who his very important in this codepen.

Maybe Try to upgrade a bit you skill code by looking HTML, CSS tutorials for understanding the basics of what you want.